# Python3.8.x - How do i use a var as an list index

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I've tried to use a var as list index because I'm writing a code to be a code decipherer to my own cryptography. But my attempt returned the IndexError: list index out of range.

My entire code below:

```
abc = 'abcdefghijklmnop'
dcd = ['', '', '', '']
n1 = int(0)
n2 = int(1)
n3 = int(2)
n4 = int(3)
n5 = int(4)


varA = input('digite o codigo: ')
while n1<5:
    n1 = n1+1
    n2 = n2+1
    n3 = n3+1
    n4 = n4+1
    n5 = n5+1
    if (varA[n1] == 'y' and varA[n2] in abc):
        dcd[n1] = 'a'
    elif (varA[n1] == 'y' and varA[n2] in abc and varA[n3] in abc):
        dcd[n1] = 'b'
    elif (varA[n1] == 'y' and varA[n2] in abc and varA[n3] in abc and varA[n4] in abc):
        dcd[n1] = 'c'
```

I really want to know if there's a different method with or without modules that works (in theory) the same way.

And thanks in advance to everyone who helps me in this matter.

OBS: Sorry if my English sounds bad, I'm Brazilian and this is my first time in StackOverFlow.

Comment: Please share the entire error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems here:

1) In Python you do not declare variables types (i.e. `list` or `int`)

2) Your `while` loop goes beyond the length of your list - it iterates from 0 to 4 (inclusive), i.e, **5** times instead of **4**.

Here are some changes that should work:

```
var = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
n = 0
while n < 4:
    print(var[n])
    n = n + 1
print('finish')
```

Comment: hint: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar

Comment: Sorry, I've accidentally informed a flawed exemple, so i decided to post the entire code. Check out xD. (I use the int() because I like to see the type of variables when I'm reading the code).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in Python, lists start at index 0. Your list has 4 items, so the highest index is 3. The condition `n <= 4` will allow the loop to continue running when n is 4, and thus it throws an error as 4 is more than your highest index (3).

You can fix it by changing `n <= 4` to `n < 4`, or even `n < len(var)` so it doesn't matter how many items there are.

Another issue was that you incremented `n` before reading the value at the index from your list. To fix this, put `n = n + 1` after `print(var[n])`

Comment: Sorry, I've accidentally informed a flawed exemple, so i decided to post the entire code. Check out xD. (I use the int() because I like to see the type of variables when I'm reading the code).

Comment: And the list doesn't start at index 0 no more starting in python3.7.x

Answer (score 0):

Line by line:

```
var = list['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

If you assign a variable with square brackets, it's automatically a list, so you don't have to state it (and would need parentheses for that to work anyway, i.e. `list(['a', 'b'])`

Also, naming a variable `var` is not a very descriptive choice, something like `letters` would probably be better. So:

```
characters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

```
n = int(0)
```

Again, you don't need to declare the type if it is implicit. `n = 0` will cause `n` to be an `int` automatically, So:

```
n = 0
```

```
while n<=4:
    n=n+1
    print(var[n])
```

Here you first increase `n` and then use it to index `var`, but `var` as a list, starts at 0 and `var[3]` is the last element, so you want that the other way around:

```
while n <= 4:
    print(var[n])
    n = n + 1
```

However, looping over a list can be done a lot easier in Python, this is nicer:

```
for ch in characters :
    print(ch)
```

This is preferred, since you don't need `n` for anything else anyway, so this is more efficient and more readable.

The whole program is then:

```
characters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
for ch in characters :
    print(ch)
print('finish')
```

Comment: Sorry, I've accidentally informed a flawed exemple, so i decided to post the entire code. Check out xD. (I use the int() because I like to see the type of variables when I'm reading the code).

Comment: In general, personal preference should probably give way to convention - you're not just writing code for yourself, you expect others to make sense of it. After all, if you didn't, there'd be little point to asking about it here. Also, there's very good reasons for Python being written the way it is - try seeing it from the language designers'  point of view before deciding you know better :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what you're trying to do, anyway, i think you're thinking as C language.
In python you don't have the counter.
A List is an Itarable.
To have the iterator over your list you can do something like :

```
var = list['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

for index in var:
  print(index)
```

OR:

```
var = list['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

print(var[0], var[1], var[2], var[3])
```